# How can I find "Install OS X Mountain Lion" (installESD.dmg) in the applications folder?

Tags: macos, applications

I've just downloaded and installed the Mountain Lion update from the Mac App Store, but when I can't find it in my applications folder.

I want to copy installESD.dmg to be able to perform a clean installation.

How can I find "Install OS X Mountain Lion" (installESD.dmg) in the applications folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets removed once you perform the update. You will have to redownload it. It may tell you it's already downloaded, use the Option key and select the 'Downloaded' button and you can download again.

Comment: You can simply download it again even with it installed. Just don't run the installer, instead open the package and use Disk Utility to make an installer flash drive or whatever.

Comment: en-sha2 Allah, that's what I'm gonna do. Thanks for your help :)